# Empty Response headers received from WebAPI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I'm using the ASP.NET WebApi with ReactJs application in the front, I'm creating a Get method to download file from the server, and I trying to set both Content-Type and Content-Length in the response headers :

```
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytes));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
```

When I'm calling this method from the ReactJs Application using fetch method like below:

```
    await fetch(`someservice/${clientid}/download/${fileName}`, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })
    .then((response) => {
        const reader = response.body.getReader();

        //get total length
        const contentLength = response.headers.get('Content-Length');
        console.log(response.headers);

        //read the data
        let receivedLength = 0; // received that many bytes at the moment
        let chunks = []; // array of received binary chunks (comprises the body)
        while (true) {
            const { done, value } = reader.read();

            if (done) {
                break;
            }
            console.log(value);
            chunks.push(value);
            receivedLength += value.length;

            console.log(`Received ${receivedLength} of ${contentLength}`)
        }

        //concatenate chunks into single Uint8Array
        let chunksAll = new Uint8Array(receivedLength);
        let position = 0;
        for (let chunk of chunks) {
            chunksAll.set(chunk, position);
            position += chunk.length;
        }
    });
```

I got a response without Content-Type and Content-Length headers:

[image: Console output]

But isn't Content-Type and Content-Length a valid headers ?

Answer (score -1):

response headers in fetch api JavaScript has been implemented as an iterator rather than an object , you could try below to access the headers :-

```
  for (var header of respone.headers.entries()) {
                    console.log(header);
                }
```

each header item in the loop will be an array of string where the first element is the key and 2nd element is value.